# Does Apache Superset supports or has similar action filter feature like in Tableau?

Tags: dashboard, interactive, action-filter, apache-superset

I am looking to build an Apache Superset interactive dashboard for one of my clients which has existing dashboards on Tableau consist of 6-7 widgets which can interact (filter) with one another at different points of clicks. I am not sure if we can code such an action filter feature in Superset. Please let me know.

If anyone is unaware of Tableau action filter please go through below link for the demo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bhhb74Zgvzo

Answer (score 0):

Create a new chart and select Filter box as visualization type. Select and configure the columns you want to filter on and add it to your dashboard.